# Reading a file after pressing a button

Tags: java, swing, java-io, jfilechooser

I have tried to create a program that lets you to choose a file,reads it and then prints the results out... This is what i have so far

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bebras braces matcher");
        JButton selectf = new JButton("Open file");
        selectf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
                if(cmd.equals("Open file")) {
                    JFileChooser chooser =new JFileChooser();
                    FileFilter filefilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("","txt");
                    chooser.setFileFilter(filefilter);
                    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);
                    if(returnVal==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        FileName=chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
                        System.out.println(FileName);       
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.add(selectf);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public static void countChar() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = null;
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(new File(FileName));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            String character = scan.next();
            int index =0;
            char close = '}';
            char open = '{';
            while(index<character.length()) {

                if(character.charAt(index)==close){
                    CloseCount++;
                }
                else if(character.charAt(index)==open) {
                    OpenCount++;
                }
                index++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Opened: "+OpenCount+"Closed: "+CloseCount);
    }
    private static String FileName;
    private static int CloseCount = 0;
    private static int OpenCount = 0;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;
}
```

And it runs okay,just doesn't do what it need to... How do I make "countChar" run? Because it doesn't print what i should..

I forgot to mention, if I call it after i print out the files name, I get this errro: "Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException", I actually know really less about those things..

Comment: Well, what should countChar do?

Comment: and where do you call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! You're just printing out the filename instead of calling that method.

See this?

```
if(returnVal==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    FileName=chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
    System.out.println(FileName);       
}
```

Instead of (or before or after, if you prefer) `System.out.println(FileName);`, just put `countChar();`.

Comment: The static fields should be replaced by local variables and arguments, though.

Comment: Absolutely, and there are a couple of other stylistic issues. But they're outside our scope today. This is the answer to the question.

Comment: I forgot to say that i tried it. I get an error: "Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException".. Like, i can not be not found because the user specifies it!

Comment: Well, a sufficiently wily user could probably pick a file that didn't really exist. But even so, `FileNotFoundException` is what's called a _checked exception_ -- which means that you're required to catch and handle the exception at some point in your program. It looks like you're doing that in `countChars`, so you can just delete `throws FileNotFoundException` from the top of that method.

Comment: (You probably want to *do* something when you catch that exception -- display an error message, or at least exit the program -- but first worry about getting it to compile.)

Comment: Thank you! Got some new errors, but I will try to solve them.."Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"" if you're interested

Comment: @Bebras, You should also not ignore the EDT and you should care about it. Read your file contents inside a SwingWorker, do not perform any non trivial work in the EDT (Why is my UI freezing sometimes or behaving strangely??).

Answer (score 0):

you just assign file name in FileName instead of file path.
so you use this

```
if(returnVal==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
FileName=chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
countChar();
```

because if file is in same directory where you project is then work but when selected file reside in different places then need to use absolutepath of selected file.